# process_template_response doesn't get called in Django

Tags: python, django

In `views.py` I use `render()` .

In app -> middleware.py I have this code:

```
from django.conf import settings


class NoTrackingMiddleware:
    def __init__(self, get_response):
        self.get_response = get_response

    def __call__(self, request):
        response = self.get_response(request)
        return response

    def process_template_response(self, request, response):
        no_tracking = True if request.GET.get("NO_TRACKING", default=False) is not False else False
        pub_id = "PUBLISHER_TEST" if no_tracking is True else settings.WFF_PUB_ID
        response.context_data["no_tracking"] = no_tracking
        response.context_data["pub_id"] = pub_id
        return response
```

In `settings.py` I have:

```
MIDDLEWARE = [
...
    'app.middleware.NoTrackingMiddleware',
]
```

Yet if I place a breakpoint at `process_template_response` it gets ignored and `pub_id` is always empty.

Why?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/http/middleware/#process-template-response) (emphasis mine):

> `process_template_response()` is called just after the view has finished executing, *if the response instance has a `render()` method, indicating that it is a `TemplateResponse` or equivalent*.

You state that you're using `django.http.shortcuts.render`, whose [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/http/shortcuts/#render) reads:

> Combines a given template with a given context dictionary and returns an `HttpResponse` object with that rendered text.
>
> Django does not provide a shortcut function which returns a `TemplateResponse` because the constructor of `TemplateResponse` offers the same level of convenience as `render()`.

Thus `render` returns a `HttpResponse`, not a `TemplateResponse`, and as noted above, `process_template_response` is only called for `TemplateResponse`s.

You either need to change your view to return `TemplateResponse`, instead of using the `render` shortcut, or perform your logic elsewhere. I think your logic could be implemented in a [context processor](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/templates/api/#writing-your-own-context-processors) instead of middleware.